# Analytic description of oscillations in a rotating frame of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, oscillators

Imagine you have a pendulum attached to a rotating axis. You define two frames of reference. In the $S$ frame, the pendulum is oscilating and rotating around this axis. The $S'$ frame is define such that the $z$ axis are the same in both frames. In the $S'$ frame the pendulum only oscilates in the $X'Z'$ plane. Here is a scheme to represent it better.

[image]

How would you describe analitically this object? The most direct way to treat with oscillations and rotations is describing the system with torque:

The Newtons Equations in the rotating frame of reference are:
$$
m \frac{d^2 \mathbf r'}{dt^2} = \mathbf F + 2m\frac{d\mathbf r'}{dt} \times \mathbf \Omega+m(\mathbf \Omega \times \mathbf r') \times \mathbf \Omega 
$$
where:
$$
\mathbf F = m\mathbf g + \mathbf T \\ \; \\
\mathbf F_{fic} = 2m\frac{d\mathbf r'}{dt} \times \mathbf \Omega+m(\mathbf \Omega \times \mathbf r') \times \mathbf \Omega 
$$
But here is my doubt. Working out the equations using:
$$
\sum_i \mathbf r_i \times \mathbf F_i =I \dot{\omega} \mathbf{\hat u}
$$
What should be the forces $\mathbf F_i$, only the inertial forces or the inertial forces plus the ficticious forces due to the rotation of the frame? And on what direction  $\mathbf{\hat u}$ should go? It should go in the $\mathbf e_y'$ direction, no? Is this the most easy way to do this?

Comment: You're missing a factor of mass for your centrifugal force term. 

Are you taking rotational velocity to be constant, or variable? If variable, you need an Euler force term. If constant, the rate of change of angular velocity is the zero vector.

Comment: Sorry, now is changed. I assumed that $\mathbf \Omega$ is constant. That is why the Euler term does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the equations of motion , use EL approach

starting with the position vector $~\mathbf P_{S'}~$ to the  CM  in  S' system

$$\mathbf P_{S'}= 
 \left[ \begin {array}{c} 1/2\,L\sin \left( \varphi  \right) 
\\ 0\\ H+1/2\,L\cos \left( 
\varphi  \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

thus  the position vector $~\mathbf P~$  in $~S~$ system is

$$\mathbf P=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \Omega\,\tau \right) &-\sin
 \left( \Omega\,\tau \right) &0\\  \sin \left( \Omega
\,\tau \right) &\cos \left( \Omega\,\tau \right) &0
\\  0&0&1\end {array} \right]\,\mathbf P_{S'}
$$

from here the kinetic energy

$$T=\frac m2\,\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf v+\frac {I_{CM}}{2}\mathbf \omega\cdot \mathbf \omega$$

where $~\mathbf v=\dot{\mathbf{P}}~$ and
$$\mathbf\omega=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\Omega\,\sin \left( \varphi  \right) 
\\  \dot\varphi \\  \cos \left( 
\varphi  \right) \Omega\end {array} \right] 
$$

the potential energy is:

$$U=-m\,g\,(\mathbf P)_z$$

applying EL you obtain

$$\ddot\varphi=
-{\frac {Lm\sin \left( \varphi  \right) 
 \left( L{\Omega}^{2}\cos \left( \varphi  \right) +2\,g \right) }{{L}^
{2}m+4\,I_{{{\it CM}}}}}$$